# How to assign a menu to a module?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Previously I was assigning the menu with featured article and in the module manager I've assigned the module to that menu. But this time I needed to show this on iphone browser, thus it is not displaying the module as it is linked to featured article.

Now I'm trying to create a article and assign that module in article by placing just simply this code `{loadposition moduleposition}` and I'm also assure that loadmodule plugin is also enabled and the module is showing but I'm having the problem.

If I assign the the menu in module manager then it doesn't display the module. And if I assign the menu in module manager then it is show two times. And if it was the same I could have displayed to none to one module. But I'm totally confused how this is appearing in my site. I tried to change the style defined in loadmodule plugin but nothing seems to vary.

[desktop site demo](http://nepotech.com/kldugar/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=130&Itemid=564&device=desktop)

[mobile site demo](http://nepotech.com/kldugar/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=130&Itemid=564&device=iphone)

So, is there any good way to assign the module in menu?

---

Anyway, If this was showing the gallery pictures like in the desktop browser in iphone browser I would have set `display: none;` to below unwanted element.

Comment: If I assign the the menu in module manager then it doesn't display the module. And if I assign the menu in module manager then it is show two times. ? you mean module on menu and menu on module manager ?

Comment: Did you see the demo? That will make you clear, there I've assigned the menu in module manager and linked the article in menu manager.

Comment: you tried both way that's why its loading twice. If you are properly assigned the module on the articles page . from module manager choose the selected page only this article. Its works

Comment: I tried every effort and I also said that if I don't assign in the module manager then it doesn't display even.

Comment: I can't see "choose the selected page only this article" and there is only these options: "on all pages", "no pages", "only on the page selected", "on all pages except those selected"

Comment: choose only on the page selected then choose your article

Comment: Yeah! I've done exactly that.

Comment: I also assure this position never repeated on any other places

Comment: mmh.. something strange!

Comment: Finally I realised there is problem in coding for the djimageslider module that is it's not displaying the images

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

On your module manager menu assignment set to on all pages.

Then use `{loadposition your_custom_position}` inside article, make sure this position never repeated on any other places(bcoz we have set the module assignment to every page so only required pages use this position).

Another option is set module to all pages and edit the template file check page like.

```
<?php if($page == "gallery"):?>
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="your_custom_position" />
<?php endif;?>
```

Second option is not good but no other way then try this too.

In first  method your load content plugin should be enabled.

Hope it helps..